# For any point $(a,b) \in\mathbb R^2$ that fulfills the condition $a+b=1$ calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} \frac{y \sin(\pi \cdot x)}{x+y-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I do not know how to even start. I suspect that these limits does not exist because $x+y-1 \rightarrow 0$ but I am not sure.

I will be very thankful for any hints.

Comment: How can you have $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ if $x+y=1$?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I corrected it.

Comment: If $b\sin(\pi a)\neq 0$ then the limit is not of indeterminate form, being $\frac{\alpha}0,$  with $\alpha\neq 0,$ so the limit does not exist. If $a,b$ are integers, you might get an interesting limit. (Reposted because I got $a,b$ backwards.)

Comment: Re-stating the comment of @ThomasAndrews, which I agree with, the posted question is more complicated than one might first suppose.  That is, for certain values of the fixed element $(a,b) \in \Bbb{R^2}$, the limit will go to infinity, while for other (fixed) values of $(a,b)$, the limit will go to a specific finite value.

Comment: @user2661923 it only “goes to infinity” if you identify $+\infty$ and $-\infty.$ And I’m not sure it converges in the other case. If $(x,y)=(a,y)$ the limit is zero, while of $(x,y)=(x,1-a)$ I think the limit is non-zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't express myself clearly enough. 
 I intended that for one specific value of $(a,b)$, the limit would go to one specific finite value, while for another specific value of $(a,b)$, the limit would go to a different specific finite value.  Also, I agree that I was careless in blurring the distinction between the limit going to $+\infty$ and the limit going to $-\infty$.